# SQL query to update item quantity using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Good morning everyone

I am trying to update the table with the new quantity selected, when I run the following function, however, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_Assessments\shoppingList\model\functions_products.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php_Assessments\shoppingList\model\functions_products.php(11): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\php_Assessments\shoppingList\controller\product_update_process.php(21): update_item('57', '3', '1') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_Assessments\shoppingList\model\functions_products.ph
```

Function to update the quantity, function_products.php:

```
<?php
function update_item($soldID, $orderedQuantity, $itemQuantity)
{
  global $conn;
  $sql = "UPDATE shopping_items.sold SET orderedQuantity = :itemQuantity WHERE soldID = :soldID";
  $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bindValue(':soldID', $soldID);
  $statement->bindValue(':orderedQuantity', $orderedQuantity);
  $statement->bindValue(':itemQuantity', $itemQuantity);
  $result = $statement->execute();
  $statement->closeCursor();
  return $result;
}

?>
```

product_update_process.php

```
<?php
// Require database connection
require('connection.php');
// Require function
require_once("../model/functions_products.php");
// Fetch the data required
$soldID = $_GET['soldID'];
$itemQuantity = $_POST['itemQuantity'];
$orderedQuantity = $_POST['orderedQuantity'];
if(empty($itemQuantity)) {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("The quantity is required.")</script>' ;
   // Redirect the browser window back to the add customer page
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = '../index.php';\",2000);</script>";
} else {
    //call the update_item() function
    $result = update_item($soldID, $itemQuantity, $orderedQuantity);
    // Redirect the browser window back to the admin page
    header("location: ../index.php"); 

}


?>
```

What could be the issue here?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Read the error message carefully and then check your code. You're binding three values to your prepared statement, but your statement has only two placeholders.

Comment: To add to @TangentiallyPerpendicular comment, why are you binding to `orderedQuantity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @TangentiallyPerpendicular's comment, why are you binding to `:orderedQuantity`?  This variable is not being used in your SQL statement, even though you have told the SQL engine to expect the variable.  The column doesn't need to be a variable in order pass a variable to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have resolved it without binding the orderedQuantity